# How to identify the subject of a sentence?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Can Python + NLTK be used to identify the subject of a sentence? From what I have learned till now is that a sentence can be broken into a head and its dependents. For e.g. "I shot an elephant". In this sentence, I and elephant are dependents to shot. But How do I discern that the subject in this sentence is I.

Comment: I wanted to link my question to a similar one asked previously - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841569/find-subject-in-incomplete-sentence-with-nltk?rq=1) and an answer given by @mjv. Perhaps the author of the question and/or the responder can shed more light. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html) (exercise 29) says, "One common way of defining the subject of a sentence S in English is as the noun phrase that is the child of S and the sibling of VP."

Look at [tree example](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html#ex-elephant): indeed, "I" is the noun phrase that is the child of S that is the sibling of VP, while "elephant" is not.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the appropriate section. I was able to identify the NP using the examples in the book, but I understand now that identifying the subject will be a combination of two criteria- child of S and sibling of VP. Can you also point me to a code example that identifies the subject in a sentence? Thanks.

Comment: This is an old post, but how do you generate the tree without manually defining it? I haven't seen that yet.

Answer (score 31):

You can use [Spacy](https://spacy.io/).

### Code

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
sent = "I shot an elephant"
doc=nlp(sent)

sub_toks = [tok for tok in doc if (tok.dep_ == "nsubj") ]

print(sub_toks)
```

Answer (score 6):

English language has two voices: Active voice and passive voice. Lets take most used voice: Active voice.

It follows `subject-verb-object` model. To mark the subject, write a rule set with POS tags. Tag the sentence `I[NOUN] shot[VERB] an elephant[NOUN]`. If you see the first noun is subject, then there is a verb and then there is an object.

If you want to make it more complicated, a sentence- `I shot an elephant with a gun`. Here the prepositions or subordinate conjunctions like with, at, in can be given roles. Here the sentence will be tagged as `I[NOUN] shot[VERB] an elephant[NOUN] with[IN] a gun[NOUN]`. You can easily say that word with gets instrumentative role. You can build a rule based system to get role of every word in the sentence.

Also look at the patterns in passive voice and write rules for the same.

Comment: How to find the active verb and passive verb?

Answer (score 1):

[`rake_nltk`](https://github.com/csurfer/rake-nltk) (`pip install rake_nltk`) is a python library that wraps `nltk` and apparently uses the RAKE algorithm.

```py
from rake_nltk import Rake

rake = Rake()

kw = rake.extract_keywords_from_text("Can Python + NLTK be used to identify the subject of a sentence?")

ranked_phrases = rake.get_ranked_phrases()

print(ranked_phrases)

# outputs the keywords ordered by rank
>>> ['used', 'subject', 'sentence', 'python', 'nltk', 'identify']
```

By default the stopword list from `nltk` is used. You can provide your custom stopword list and punctuation chars by passing them in the constructor:

```
rake = Rake(stopwords='mystopwords.txt', punctuations=''',;:!@#$%^*/\''')
```

By default [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation) is used for punctuation.

The constructor also accepts a `language` keyword which can be any language supported by `nltk`.

Comment: is there any way in js ?

Answer (score 0):

Stanford Corenlp Tool can also be used to extract Subject-Relation-Object information of a sentence.

Attaching screenshot of same:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

code using spacy :
here the doc is the sentence and dep='nsubj' for subject and 'dobj' for object

```py
import spacy 
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')


def get_subject_object_phrase(doc, dep):
    doc = nlp(doc)
    for token in doc:
        if dep in token.dep_:
            subtree = list(token.subtree)
            start = subtree[0].i
            end = subtree[-1].i + 1
    return str(doc[start:end])
```

Answer (score -3):

You can paper over the issue by doing something like `doc = nlp(text.decode('utf8'))`, but this will likely bring you more bugs in future.

Credits: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/380

Comment: ? I don't understand this answer.

Comment: That issue is about giving non-unicode data to Spacy. Nothing to do with this question.