# Can Spacy be used to find a sentence subject that's multiple words long?

Tags: python, space, sentence, subject

I've recently started playing around with Python's Spacy library. I wanted to use it to find the subject of a sentence. I used the method detailed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41202178/4891743), but it doesn't find the entire subject.

For Example:

```
doc = nlp(u"Mr Bob Bobson enjoyed hunting and fishing")
sub_toks = [tok for tok in doc if (tok.dep_ == "nsubj")]
print(sub_toks)
```

Results in

```
[Bobson]
```

However, the result I want is

```
[Mr Bob Bobson]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the `tok.subtree` [API docs](https://spacy.io/docs/api/token).

```
np = doc[tok.left_edge.i : tok.right_edge.i + 1]
```

Comment: When I enter this, it throws this NameError: name 'tok' is not defined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `tok` has to be a spacy `Token` type, (though you can call it whatever you want).

Comment: @Xeoncross do you mind providing a complete code sample for the question?