# Using python to flag offensive language in text?

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

Is there any way one can use python to analyse and flag offensive language in reviews. The catch here is to identify sentences and not just words. I am not asking for a code here,just want advice on the approach.
I am assuming nltk will be the place to start!? Any thoughts / guidance will be appreciated,thanks!

Comment: You can do it, even for sentences. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618400/how-to-identify-the-subject-of-a-sentence) for now.

Comment: Thanks I will surely have a look

Comment: Take a look at https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=expletives+github (Shamless plug: https://github.com/alvations/expletives)